# Need help to figure out how to make a class inherit a level variable

Tags: python, game-development

I have a class that has a level variable that is given on the definition of the instance, but I want to access it on a child class so that I can use it to scale a health variable. I cant get it to be a variable and can only have it as a fixed number which is no good.

```
    import random

    # --- Stand Battle Game --- #

    # --- Characters --- #

    class Character():
      def __init__(self, level, stand, regenRate):
        self.level = level
        self.health = 100 + (10 * self.level)
        self.energy = 100 + (10 * self.level)
        self.stand = stand
        self.regen = regenRate
    
    # --- Characters --- #

    # --- Stands --- #

    class Stand(Character):
      def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(level, self, 0)
        self.name = name
        self.health = self.health * 10
        self.energy = self.energy * 10

    class TheWorld(Stand):
      def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("The World")

    class StarPlatinum(Stand):
      def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Star Platinum")

    # --- Stands --- #

    # --- Game Function --- #

    # Fighting #
    # Fighting #

    # Get Stand #

    def getStand(character, standList):
      if useArrow() is True and standChance() is True:
        character.stand = standList[random.randint(0,len(standList)-1)]
        return "You have gained the stand: " + character.stand
    
    def useArrow():
      return input("You find a small stone arrowhead: A. Use B. Leave - ") == "A"

    def standChance():
      return random.randint(1,3) == 1  

    # Get Stand #

    # --- Game Function --- #

    playerCharacter = Character(0, None, 0)

    Dio = Character(10, TheWorld(), 10)

    standList = [
      TheWorld(),
      StarPlatinum()
    ]

    #getStand(playerCharacter, standList)

    print(Dio.stand.health)
```

The problem is at `super().__init__(level, self, 0)` where I tried to use self.level instead of level but it takes that as using the `class TheWorld()`. Help is appreciated

Comment: The constructors of the child classes need a `level` parameter which can then given via the `super`-constructor call to `Character`.

Comment: im not sure if it makes sense but wouldnt that make the level stem from the child classes and not the parent Character

Comment: Well, your question is a bit confusing.  The `Character` base class requires that a `level` be passed in.  That means the `Stand` constructor MUST pass a level when it calls `super().__init__`.  Where is it going to get that level?

Comment: What do you mean with "stem from"? The value of `level` would be transferred through one or more constructors upward to the `Character` constructor and there it is stored as instance variable.

Comment: My thinking was that when I create the `playerCharacter` instance that the level given there would be `self.level` and then it would be inherited by the `Stand` class and be usable there.

Comment: I think you don't understand inheritance. There aren't two different objects, there's just one object. `Stand` is a kind of `Character`. When you call `super().__init__()` you're just initializing the `Character` aspects of the `Stand`. Where are the parameters like `level` going to come from if not the parameters to `Stand.__init__()`?

Comment: From your explanation I am thinking that maybe inheritance is the wrong way to go for what I am trying to do. What I am trying to achieve is that the Stand only exists as an object within the character and that the attributes of the stand are determined by the characters attributes which are passed in as parameters